# Get Values from DataTable by row and column name

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, datatable

I'm typically used to traditional table in `SQL` where I have multiple `columns` with rows populated. I execute a stored procedure and store all the data in `DataTable` and loop through the table to get the results I need. For example,

```
 public static DataTable getInfo (string sessionID)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SandBox"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetSessionInfo", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SessionGUID", sessionID);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

I would load the DataTable:

```
 DataTable infoTbl = new DataTable();
 infoTbl = getInfo(lbldatabasesessionID.Text);
```

And I would use `foreach` loop to loop through the DataTable.

```
foreach (DataRow row in infoTbl.Rows)
{
   string x = col.ToString();
}
```

The issue I run into is the database guy gave me a stored procedure that returns a different output *(different from what I'm used to)*. It's a row based.

[image]

The only way I can access for example the `First Name` is if I hard code the position like:

```
string firstName = infoTbl.Rows[16][2].ToString();
```

I don't feel comfortable doing this since the position could potentially change. How would I access `ElementValue` by knowing the name knowing `ElementType` and `ElementName`?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using DataSet:

```
        string firstName = string.Empty;

        DataRow row = table.Select("ElementType = 'Demographics' AND ElementName = 'FirstName'").FirstOrDefault();

        if (row != null)
        {
            firstName = (string)row["ElementValue"];
        }
```

Using Linq:

```
        string firstName = table.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(f => f.Field<string>("ElementType") == "Demographics" && 
                f.Field<string>("ElementName") == "FirstName")
            .Select(f => f.Field<string>("ElementValue")).FirstOrDefault();
```